# install_github not working in R

Tags: r

Everytime I try to use the install_github functionality in R 3.6.1, I get hit with this HTTP error 404 error message. Any ideas?

```
install_github("maxmind/libmaxminddb")
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a C library not an R package.

Comment: This explains so much. I'm so sorry - I feel like an idiot now.